How to merge disk partitions?
I have 57.18 GiB of unallocated disk space that I want to add to my /dev/sda4 partition, but I'm unable to do so. How can I resolve this issue?
OS: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS


There is good information here https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions

Basically you need to boot into a live session so your root partition is not locked. You need to move the ntfs media partition to the end of the drive and resize the root partition. Many people recommend using windows tools to move windows  partitions. I’ve used the MiniTool partition wizard with success. Use that in Windows first

Suggestion: Create a new ext4 partition and mount it on your /home, for example as ~/Data, this way your data is not at risk, it is easier and faster, and for Ubuntu use it makes no difference.

This question is similar to: How to resize partitions?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
